# My laptop has no internet

Tags: windows, internet

My school issued work laptop suddenly has no internet. The tech support guy will literally re image all problems and I have lots of useful files. I tried plugging in an ethernet cord now, the only sites I can access are stackexchange sites... such as https://superuser.com/questions/ask (what the dell?????) and http://pages.eimacs.com/ the only similarities i found between the two sites are that they both have non https and there is no www. As soon as i add the www. it gives this error

```
Server not found

Firefox can't find the server at www.pages.eimacs.com.

    Check the address for typing errors such as ww.example.com instead of www.example.com
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

so please very help.

Also this is the laptop model... its a stupid cheap terrible laptop
Dell Lattitude 3330

Comment: Are there any web sites that actually exist that you can't reach?

Comment: www.eimacs.com/eimacs/signin is the same as pages.eimacs.com/eimacs/signin

Comment: Try connecting to http://google.com and http://62.1.38.158. Do they both fail?

Answer (score 3):

If it is a school issued laptop, they should be able to support/fix the issue. If their idea of fixing is to re-image the system, buy a USB drive to grab a copy of all the files you do not want to lose and give them the system to re-image.

It would be very difficult without having knowledge of the system configuration or the networks you should be connecting to for anyone to be able to advise you on a possible cause.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously if you try to access a site using a name that's not that site's name, you'll get an error. There is no site called "www.pages.eimacs.com", so of course you won't be able to access such a site.

Comment: +1. `www.` is not a generic string that you can put before any URL. Some servers may be configured to support both `www` and `www`-less requests, but it's not guaranteed to work on every single page.

Answer (score 0):

http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_latitude_laptop/latitude-3330-laptop_Owner%27s%20Manual_en-us.pdf is the manual for that laptop. Please check page 34 for the instructions on turning the wireless off and on.

If that does not resolve it, please make a [LiveUSB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) or LiveDVD of [Linux Mint 17.1](http://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=172), [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) or some other well-supported Linux distro. Boot from it (which will not interfere with your Windows install), and see if a different operating system solves the problem. If so, you know the problem is in Windows, and must be solved by the school's sysadmin.

Comment: +1 for linux live usbs. Unfortunately kali doesnt connect to the wifi either. Kali couldent connect before it was broke aswell.

Comment: Well, try remove - reinsert the wifi card along with booting with a  more popular distro of LiveUSB.